# Classical Cohen's d effect sizes within mixed-effects models

Tags: mixed-model, effect-size

I am trying to get a passable effect size estimate of group differences in slope from a trend analysis, run by specifying custom polynomial contrasts within a factorial mixed-effects model. [This](http://jakewestfall.org/blog/index.php/2016/03/25/five-different-cohens-d-statistics-for-within-subject-designs/) blog-post by Jake Westfall offers ways of calculating a classical Cohen's-d effect from a within-subject design posted by [Jeff Rouder](http://jeffrouder.blogspot.com/2016/03/the-effect-size-puzzler-answer.html). In the final comment at the bottom of the page Westfall suggests a method of obtaining a classical cohen's *d* using only a *t* statistic and the group *n*. I was wondering if the same method could be applied to t-statistics of the coefficients in the output of `lmer`s etc, or even to the t statistic for custom constrasts within a mixed-effects model?

Here is an example using toy data, two groups of *n*=4  participants, each group with differing intercepts and slopes. The analysis requires `lsmeans`, `ggplot2`, and `lme4` packages.

```
# toy data. differing intercepts and slopes. Group A starts on 2, increases by 4 with 
# each additional time point. Group B starts on 5 but only increases by 3 
# at each additional time point. 

set.seed(1234)
A0 <- rnorm(4,2,.5)
B0 <- rnorm(4,2+3,.5)
A1 <- rnorm(4,6,.5)
B1 <- rnorm(4,6+2,.5)
A2 <- rnorm(4,10,.5)
B2 <- rnorm(4,10+1,.5)
A3 <- rnorm(4,14,.5)
B3 <- rnorm(4,14+0,.5)
score <- c(A0,B0,A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3)
id <- factor(rep(1:8,times = 4, length = 32))
time <- factor(rep(0:3, each = 8, length = 32))
group <- rep(c("A","B"), times =2, each = 4, length = 32)
df <- data.frame(id = id, group = group, time = time, score = score)

# plots
(ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = score, group = group)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", aes(linetype = group)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", aes(shape = group), fill = "white", size = 3) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,18)))

# now analyse as a between*within mixed effects model
catSum <- summary(catMod <- lmer(score ~ group*time + (1|id), data = df))
```

Now for my first question. Could we get Cohen's d effect sizes by applying the formula t/sqrt(2/n) to each coefficient, like so

```
lmerDF <- as.data.frame(catSum$coefficients)
lmerDF$d <- lmerDF$`t value`*sqrt(2/4)
lmerDF
```

Now for the trend analysis, testing group differences in slope

```
# reference grid
catRG <- ref.grid(catMod)

# lsmeans
(catLS <- lsmeans(catRG, ~ time:group))

# main effects
mainGroup <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

# normalising
(nGroups <- 2)
(trendIncrem <- 2) # the increments that the trend contrasts increase by
(trendMat <- c(-3, -1, 1, 3, -3, -1, 1, 3))
(trendNorm <- trendIncrem/(sum(trendMat^2)))
(contMainTrendNorm <- trendMat*trendNorm)

# make a list of the contrast matrices to pass into the contrast function
cons <- list("difference in slopes" = (mainGroup*trendMat)*(nGroups*trendNorm))

# run it
contrast(catLS, cons

# output
# contrast             estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
# difference in slopes 1.034703 0.1535162 24    6.74  <.0001
```

So we have successfully retrieved the group difference in slope we specified in the toy data (i.e. a group difference in rate of increase of 1 unit per timepoint). Now my second question: Could I use the same method above to calculate a cohen's d for a difference in slope, based on group size and t-statistic?

```
6.74*sqrt(6.74/4)
# [1] 8.749029
```

I know I'm getting something wrong because nothing in life is this easy, and this latter *d* seems far too large, even for unrealistically uniform toy data. Westfall and Rouder's example was within-subject only, so I'm pretty sure this is wrong. Any advice (including 'don't bother with standardised effect sizes in mixed models') would be appreciated. I have a reviewer crawling up my tradesman's entrance about this and would like to mollify them, either by doing as they wish or telling them it's best not to try.

I know there are already a lot of questions related to this topic on CV but I figured that because this was very specific it could probably stand as a non-duplicate.

Comment: possible duplcate? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257985/how-can-i-derive-effect-sizes-in-lme4-and-describe-the-magnitude-of-fixed-effect