# Help understanding Cohen's D for pairwise comparisons in lme

Tags: lme4-nlme, effect-size, lsmeans, cohens-d

I've been asked by a reviewer to provide effect sizes for pairwise, planned comparisons. In the experimental design, I have one fixed factor with three conditions (Consistency). Passage & Subject are random effects. I would like to report Cohen's D for three planned comparisons (Consistency 1 - Consistency2; Consistency 1 - Consistency3; Consistency2 - Consistency3). However, when I compute Cohen's D, I get two effect sizes, one labelled Consistency 2 (d = .732), and the other labelled as Consistency 3 (d = .296). First, I'm not sure which comparisons these effect sizes refer to and the output only provides two effect sizes. And second, how can I get Cohen's D for the third comparison?

Here is my code:

```
PdatFIN$RT_target <- as.numeric(PdatFIN$RT_target)
PdatFIN$Consistency <- as.factor(PdatFIN$Consistency)
str(PdatFIN)
m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage), PdatFIN); summary(m); Anova(m)
lme.dscore(m,data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
m.contrasts <- emmeans(m,"Consistency")
pairs(m.contrasts)
```

Here is my output:

```
group: 1
             vars   n    mean     sd median trimmed    mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
RT_target       1 148 1709.04 527.09   1631 1697.14 650.12 846 2974  2128 0.22    -1.06 43.33
group: 2
             vars   n    mean     sd median trimmed    mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
RT_target       1 162 2137.73 741.01 2056.5 2081.52 717.58 897 4414  3517 0.70     0.34 58.22
group: 3
             vars   n    mean     sd median trimmed    mad min  max range skew kurtosis    se
RT_target       1 166 1888.73 736.85   1740 1811.35 708.68 750 4318  3568 1.01     0.83 57.19

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT_target ~ Consistency + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage)
   Data: PdatFIN

REML criterion at convergence: 7314.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0682 -0.6320 -0.1771  0.5346  4.1376 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 203923   451.6   
 Passage  (Intercept)  23091   152.0   
 Residual             239054   488.9   
Number of obs: 476, groups:  Subject, 30; Passage, 18

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   1711.58      98.75  17.333
Consistency2   427.71      56.19   7.612
Consistency3   173.18      55.99   3.093

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Cnsst2
Consistncy2 -0.301       
Consistncy3 -0.303  0.532
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: RT_target
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Consistency 59.216  2  1.385e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> #Cohens d
> lme.dscore(m,data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
                    t       df         d
Consistency2 7.612028 432.5373 0.7320127
Consistency3 3.092820 434.6247 0.2967068
> m.contrasts <- emmeans(m,"Consistency")
> pairs(m.contrasts)
 contrast                    estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 Consistency1 - Consistency2     -428 56.2 432  -7.607  <.0001
 Consistency1 - Consistency3     -173 56.1 434  -3.090  0.0060
 Consistency2 - Consistency3      255 54.3 429   4.688  <.0001

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

I really appreciate the help and guidance. I'm new to LME and it's been a challenge trying to interpret my output. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cohen's d's you get are for Consistency1 vs. Consistency2 and Consistency1 vs Consistency3. You get the final d (C2 vs. C3) by changing your reference group: e.g.

```
m2<-lmer(RT_target ~ relevel(Consistency, ref=2) + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Passage), PdatFIN) #note that Consistency needs to be an unordered factor for releveling to work

lme.dscore(m2, data=PdatFIN,type = "lme4")
```

(There may be a more elegant way that I don't know about, but this at least gives you the final d relatively easily)

However, please note that computing effect sizes from multilevel (mixed) models is controversial; see for instance [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410812/cohens-d-from-mixed-method-model-for-the-interaction-term) and [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358927/compute-partial-eta2-for-all-fixed-effects-anovas-from-a-lme4-model) and [this discussion](https://afex.singmann.science/forums/topic/compute-effect-sizes-for-mixed-objects#post-295). It may be better to just report the estimated marginal means or contrast estimates along with CIs and/or p-values.

Comment: Thank you so much, your feedback is very helpful. I did come across some of the controversy regarding effect sizes and mixed modeling in my search and rather not report them; however, I need to satisfy the reviewers (although, I like your suggestion to consider reporting estimates and CIs). The reviewer asked for Bayes Factors or effect sizes for the planned comparisons. I computed Bayes Factors but not sure if I did them correctly. I guess I can add another post! Again, thanks so much for your help!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! And yes, I forgot while typing that it was a reviewer request, probably best to give them what they want :)